# How can we calculate number of subsets by classifying each based on the number of elements?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I am aware of that the number of subsets of a set with n elements is ${2^n}$

However, I tried doing it my own way, by simply listing the number of null, unit, two-element, etc. subsets and adding the total.

So suppose I were to find the number of subsets of a set with 10 elements, then:

Number of null subsets = 1

Number of unit subsets = 10

Number of subsets containing 2 elements= 10 x 9

Number of subsets containing 3 elements = 10 x 9 x 8

Number of subsets containing 4 elements = 10 x 9 x 8 x 7

. 
.
.

Number of subsets containing n elements =10!

Generalising the same for a set containing n elements, the formula looks like

$\sum_ {i=n}^1 \prod_ {j=n}^i j$

Now if the above formula is true, then ideally

$\sum_ {i=n}^1 \prod_ {j=n}^i j$ =  ${2^n}$

However, that doesn't seem to  be the case.
Where did I go wrong, and how can we calculate the number of subsets if we were to go my way?

Comment: The number of elements with two subsets is $\binom {10}2$, not $10\times 9$.  And so on.

Comment: The number of subsets containing two elements is $\frac{10\times 9}{2}$, the number of subsets containing $3$ elements is $\frac{10\times 9\times 8}{6}$ and so on.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path But why is it so?

Comment: @SashankSriram Because sets don't carry information about the permutation of its elements. There are $10 \cdot 9$ many ways to form a vector $(x,y)$ with $x,y \in \{1, \ldots, 10 \}$ and $x \neq y$. However, as sets $\{x,y\} = \{y,x\}$, so we have to divide the number of vectors we can form by the number of permutations they allow.

Comment: @Stefan Mesken Oh, so you mean to say that the order of the elements doesn't matter. Understood.